# Android: ViewGroup Overlapping When Adding Children within Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, overlap, viewgroup

My situation is as follows:
In my layout xml, I have a general LinearLayout serving as a master container and I want to populate the contents based on a paging system all contained within the single activity.

My Java Code is as follows:

```
private void goToPage(int pageNum){
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.layoutRadioGroups);

    //Clear Views
    layout.removeAllViews();

    //Figure out array positions based on page number
    if (pageNum < this.PAGE_NUM)
        this.LAST_QUESTION_START -= this.NUM_PER_PAGE[pageNum];
    else{
        if (pageNum > 0)
            this.LAST_QUESTION_START += this.NUM_PER_PAGE[pageNum - 1];
        else
            this.LAST_QUESTION_START = 0;
    }
    this.PAGE_NUM = pageNum;

    //Grab my array values, create a TextView, and add it to the layout
    for (int i=this.LAST_QUESTION_START; i < this.LAST_QUESTION_START + this.NUM_PER_PAGE[pageNum]; i++){
        TextView tv = new TextView(layout.getContext());
        tv.setText(this.QUESTIONS[i]);
        tv.setId(i);
        layout.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

So it clears all views (which would be only TextView's), figures out the correct array values that will formulate the TextView objects, then adds them to my layout.

Now Page 0 displays correct, when I click my next button, page 1 displays correctly as well. But when I go to page 2, the contents from page 1 are still there, and the contents from page 2 are overlayed on top.

I'm fairly new to Android Development so I'm not sure I'm not refreshing something or invalidating something, but I'm puzzled. Any ideas folks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

This overlap issue only happens if you have the android:windowBackground set to @null for the application.

This overlap issue would even happen if you're just setting the text of a textview to the array values. You don't have to actually add views to a layout or anything.

Moral of the story, set things up properly at the beginning.

That being said, does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?